# Revolution Slider - Display caption under slider

Tags: wordpress, caption, revolution-slider

I am trying to build a carousel and slider. The images can be both light and dark so I do not want the caption on top of the slider image.

There is none like this in the [example sliders](https://revolution.themepunch.com/examples/) and in the editor the element disappears if you drag it all the way down.

I specifically want Revolution Slider and not any other slider.

Comment: What you can try (without any guaranty, is to put a bottom margin in your background images (with the same margin size the same color that your background). Then you will change your height general settings.This should do the trick to have the captions on bottom out-side your images.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS and it's responsive:

```
.rev_slider li.tp-revslider-slidesli {
overflow: visible !important;
height: 150% !important;
}

.fullwidthbanner-container .fullwidthabanner {
max-height: none !important;
height: 150% !important;
}

.tp-bgimg.defaultimg {
height: 35% !important;
}

.tp-caption.NotGeneric-Title, 
.NotGeneric-Title,
.tp-caption.NotGeneric-Title a, 
.NotGeneric-Title a {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: 'voorregular' !important;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    font-weight: 300!important;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px !important;
}
```